# strange behaviour of arange in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I thought that in arange the second argument will never be comprised in the list,
but see what happens in Python 2.7.3.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.arange(0.2,0.9,0.1)
array([ 0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8])
>>> numpy.arange(0.2,0.7,0.1)
array([ 0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6])
>>> numpy.arange(0.2,0.6,0.1)
array([ 0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5])
```

but

```
>>> numpy.arange(0.2,0.8,0.1)
array([ 0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8])
```

Does anybody know the reason for this behaviour ?

Comment: If you want to control the inclusion or exclusion of the endpoint, use [numpy.linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html): `np.linspace(0.2, 0.8, 6, endpoint=False)` or `np.linspace(0.2, 0.7, 6)`.

Comment: @unutbu In fact the documentation of `numpy.arange` specifically says to prefer `linspace` when the step is a floating point.

Comment: Also, this is a numpy issue, not a python issue.

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem with floating-point precision.

From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

> **stop** *: number*
>
> End of interval. The interval does not include this value, except in
>   some cases where step is not an integer and floating point round-off
>   affects the length of out.

To see more about the limitations of floats, look at Python's [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Answer (score 4):

```
In [169]: val = 0.2

In [170]: for i in range(6): #simulating the loop in arange.
   .....:     val += 0.1
   .....:

In [171]: val
Out[171]: 0.7999999999999999
```

floating point rounding error. The result being that the last value is also printed.